# in VBA, how to find a file in dir by text value sorting

Tags: vba, excel

i am reading files from dir in VBA Excel. 
after reading i am writing the files in cells.
Problem is directory is searched in file name ascending order. but i need to print in order of partial text(number inside the file name)

For ex:

```
image_100
image_120
image_1205
image_123
```

i need solution to print like

```
image_100
image_120
image_123
image_1205
```

[ascend as per last values)
Any help friends?

thanks,
kamal.

Comment: Have you tried collecting all of the filenames into an array first then custom sorting the array and then processing them?

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this would be to put the sort values into another column (I've assumed the filenames are in Column A and used Column B for the sort fields in this example)

```
Public Sub ReOrderFiles()

    Columns("B:B").Clear

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    Dim dr As Range
    Set dr = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    dr.Select

    Dim target As Range

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In dr.Cells

        Set target = Range("B" & c.Row)
        target.Select
        If Len(c.Value2) > 0 Then
            Selection.Value = "Sort" & onlyEndDigits(c.Value2)
        End If
    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:B")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Columns("B:B").Clear

End Sub
```

An the function for getting the numbers at the end could be

```
Function onlyEndDigits(s As String) As String
    Dim retval As String
    Dim Start As Integer

    retval = ""
    Start = 1

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid$(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid$(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            Start = i
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For i = Start To Len(s)
        retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
    Next

    onlyEndDigits = retval
End Function
```

Note this function will ignore any digits that appear elsewhere in the filename

Comment: In VBA, `Mid(s, i)` would be sufficient to get everything from **i** to the end of **s** but I have a feeling that the [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) is actually going to return something like **Image_120.jpg** or **Image_123.png**.

Comment: @Jeeped - good points. Based on the OPs sample data I assumed that they had already stripped off the extension, but I completely forgot about being able to omit the length using Mid()